# Nginx + php-fpm random hang

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx

I have a website made with Codeigniter, running on Ubuntu with Nginx and PHP-FPM.
It worked fine till last night, when it started loading pages really slow, sometimes giving 504, other times loading pages fast.

If I restart nginx or php-fpm, the site works fine for 20-30 seconds, then the problem occur again.

Here's what nginx error log says:

> [error] 25226#25226: *65 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed
>   out) while reading response header from upstream, client: X.X.X.X,
>   server: www.mydomain.ext, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock:", host:
>   "www.mydomain.ext"

I've been googling and playing around with nginx and php-fpm config for the last few hours, but I couldn't solve it.

Does anyone know how to help me?

Comment: Does your application interact with a database? I have received this message before due to not being able to connect to my database server, or a query taking longer to complete then the max_execution_time of the fpm process.

Answer (score 2):

To me it looks like a problem with the FPM process management. See this [link](https://serversforhackers.com/c/php-fpm-process-management) for more information.  It's seems like you have static number of processes available for php-fpm and traffic is exceeding it. I was facing similar issues, but I don't remember if this was the exact error message back then. But the behavior was like you explained, some connections were really slow (Waiting for fpm?) other were returning 504.

UPDATE:
To confirm my theory you should check the file `/etc/php5.6/pool.d/www.conf` and check this line:

```
pm.max_children = X
```

Increase the number and restart fpm. Then see if problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your config as follows :

```
pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 200
pm.process_idle_timeout = 1s
pm.max_requests = 1000
```

restart fpm and your problem should be solved.